# How to save cookie with line break in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to save the value of a textarea into a cookie using Javascript.

The problem comes when the user enters multiple lines. Only the first line is saved and subsequent directives are ignored.

e.g.

```
var myText = $('#mytextarea').val();
document.cookie = "mycookie=" + myText + "; path=/;"
```

if `myText` contains the `\n` character which it does if the user entered multiple lines in the textarea field, then not only are the rest of the lines not stored in the cookie, but the `path=/;` is ignored.

Comment: You might need to double-escape the backslash so you're storing `\\n` in the string. Then when reading the cookie process it back from `\\n` => `\n`

Answer (score 10):

Further to my comment about escaping the newline, the [MDN cookie documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) has this note in the [Write a new cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#new-cookie_syntax) section:

> The cookie value string can use [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to ensure that the string does not contain any commas, semicolons, or whitespace (which are disallowed in cookie values).

You can then use [decodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) when reading the cookie value back to get the original text.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is replacing the line breaks "\n" with another character, like the "\" (backslash), that I'm sure will not be used.

```
var myText = $('#mytextarea').val();
var myCookieValue = myText.split('\n').join('\\');
document.cookie = "mycookie=" + myCookieValue + "; path=/;"
```

And when you read the cookie, just make the reverse conversion:

`var cookie = rawValue.split('\\').join('\n');`